# Why does Python say that I am giving 64 arguments for a function when I am only giving 1 each time with a for loop?

Tags: python, multithreading

I'm making a dictionary attack with SHA-256 hashes from Violent Python and I have a function which tests the hash and sees if it matches the password. Then I have a main() function.

The program opens a dictionary file and a UNIX-style sheet with users and their hashes passwords.
I am using threads to test the words all at once, and using a for loop to test them:

```
from hashlib import *
from os import chdir
from pathlib import Path
from threading import Thread
from time import sleep

chdir(Path.home() / 'Downloads')
dict = open('dictionary.txt')

def test(encrypted):
    for word in dict.readlines():
        hash = sha256()
        word = word.strip('\n')
        hash.update(bytes(word))
        if hash.hexdigest() == encrypted:
            print('Match!:' + word)
        else:
            return null
def main():
    users = open('users.txt')
    for line in users.readlines():
        user = line.split(':')[0]
        encrypted = line.split(':')[1].strip(' ')
        print('cracking for' + user + '...')
        t = Thread(target = test, args = encrypted)
        t.start()
main()
sleep(200)
```

Python gives me this error though:

```
TypeError: test() takes 1 positional argument but 64 were given
```

I think Python thinks I am trying to test all the dictionary words at once, but that is impossible because there are not 64 words in my dictionary, yet I can't find anything else wrong with the code.

```
apple
orange
egg
lemon
grapes
secret
strawberry
password
```

Here is the users.txt:

```
victim: 34707c3f40dfa20c3902b807b627d420d6d474d9d98066ba637953d1cfd6b914: 503:100:Iama Victim:/home/victim:/bin/sh
root: 3a7bd3e2360a3d29eea436fcfb7e44c735d117c42d1c1835420b6b9942dd4f1b: 504:100: Markus Hess:/root:/bin/bash
```

Comment: `encrypted` is 64 characters long, you should read what `args` means when you create a `Thread`: https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Thread

Comment: @jonrsharpe So should I put it in a tuple?

Comment: Try it; does doing so make a difference?

Comment: @jonsharpe Yes, it does. But for some reason it only works when I put a comma after it like CopyrightC wrote. Thanks!

Comment: The comma's what _makes it a tuple_, if you just did `args=(encrypted)` that would make no difference at all.

Answer (score 0):

The args keyword of a Thread accepts a tuple

This might work :

```py
t = Thread(target = test, args = (encrypted,))
```

Also there's nothing like `null` in python but `none`